# How to import Java classes in VS Code?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

As part of a school club I have to read a JSON file using Java in VS Code. I have little experince with Java and VS, I'm usually the Python guy, so this might be obvious.

I found this seemingly great [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm) but it says "we have downloaded and installed JSON.simple and have added the location of json-simple-1.1.1.jar file to the environment variable CLASSPATH." But I have no clue how to do this. It seems that I have to compile [this](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple) to a jar file, which I am also unable to figure out, due to my inexperience with Java. No one else can figure it out and google searches have been less than enlightening. Any advice or pushes in the right direction would help.

Note: Currently my CLASSPATH file looks like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
 <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-10"/>
 <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
 <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: Are you sure they don't mean JavaScript? Isn't vs code for web designers? If it's just JSON then JavaScript seems more likely. JSON.parse to read JSON to an object.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the tutorial is about Java, and I am unfortunately required to use Java and VS, even though that's not the best way to do it.